# sub queries for each event in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have tables consisting of

1. **race**

-race_id

-athlete_id

-place

2.**prize**

-race_id

-place

-money

I now need to run a query for each race listing the prize money for first, second, and third place?? I know how to retrieve results for all races for all places:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    prize
GROUP BY race_id , place;
```

however, I do need column headings to be displayed as such

**RACE_ID | FIRST | SECOND | THIRD**

I have tried running this following SQL, however, receive error message "ErrorCode:1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row" SELECT race_id, 'First', 'Second', Third' FROM prize WHERE 'First' = (SELECT money FROM prize WHERE place IN (1)) AND WHERE 'Second' = (SELECT money FROM prize WHERE place IN (2)) AND WHERE 'Third' = (SELECT money FROM prize WHERE place IN (3)) ORDER BY race_id; I understand that sub-queries require statements to be scalar, therefore, does this mean I will need to run individual sub-queries for each race_id?

Comment: What you're trying to do is often called a "pivot."

Comment: @jimmytiler, I didn't get why u unaccepted answer

Comment: sorry radar. although your answer does get the results I need, I do need it to be in sub-query form. I posted another in this post with the SQL I am trying to achieve. I'm so lost on this one??

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `case based aggregation` , in other DBMS ,you can do it with `pivot` clause.

```
SELECT 
    race_id,
    max(case when place =1 then money else NULL end) as FIRST,
    max(case when place =2 then money else NULL end) as SECOND,
    max(case when place =3 then money else NULL end) as THIRD,

FROM
    prize
GROUP BY
    race_id
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this??

```
SELECT a.race_id, 
       a.place, 
       b.athlete_id, 
       a.money
FROM prize a join race b 
on   a.place = b.place 
AND  a.race_id = b.race_id;
```

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I need it to be nested though(sub-queries).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result you want using conditional aggregation (as RADAR suggests).  Or you can do multiple joins:

```
select r.*, p1.money as first, p2.money as second, p3.money as third
from race r left join
     prize p1
     on p1.race_id = r.race_id and p1.place = 1 left join
     prize p2
     on p2.race_id = r.race_id and p2.place = 2 left join
     prize p3
     on p3.race_id = r.race_id and p3.place = 3;
```

Comment: Is it possible to use somewhat nesting as such: 

SELECT <column.name>, <column.name>, column.name>
FROM <table.name>
WHERE <table.name> IN
 (SELECT <column.name>, <column.name>
  FROM <table.name>
  WHERE <column.name> =#); 
 
From my instructions, I am asked to ‘test’ each statement before combining it all together so I’m assuming multiple nesting??

Comment: I suppose so.  @radar's solution seems simplest.  I offered this as an alternative.